# Flutter: I have a problem displaying my page

Tags: flutter, dart

Here is the code that I have in my page, but nothing is displayed:

```dart
body: Column(
        children: [
          Center(
            child: Container(
              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 234, 237, 245),
              child: Expanded(
                child: ListView.separated(
                  separatorBuilder: (context, index) => SizedBox(
                    height: 2,
                  ),
                  controller: scrollController,
                  itemCount: 2,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/seconnecter");
                      },
                      title: Text('hello'),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Please tell me where is the error?

What I expected to have: A page with `Column` and `Row`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Expanded the wrong way.

*A widget that expands a child of a **Row, Column, or Flex** so that the child fills the available space.*

*Using an **Expanded** widget makes a child of a **Row, Column, or Flex** expand to fill the available space along the main axis (e.g., **horizontally for a Row or vertically for a Column**). If multiple children are expanded, the available space is divided among them according to the flex factor.*

*An Expanded widget must be a descendant of a **Row, Column, or Flex**, and the path from the Expanded widget to its enclosing **Row, Column, or Flex** must contain only StatelessWidgets or StatefulWidgets (not other kinds of widgets, like RenderObjectWidgets).*

From the above explanation, You can't use a ListView.separated (which is a scrollable widget).

You can rather do this:

```
body: Column(
      children: [
        Center(
          child: Container(
            color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 234, 237, 245),
            child: ListView.separated(
              shrinkWrap: true, //<===== take note of this
              separatorBuilder: (context, index) => const SizedBox(
                height: 2,
              ),
              controller: scrollController,
              itemCount: 2,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/seconnecter");
                  },
                  title: const Text('hello'),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    )
```